# Rstudio Rmarkdown ouput is different than html and pdf

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio, r-markdown

I am using RStudio 1.0.44 and I when I run a code chunk in an RMarkdown document, the ouptut looks great but when knit to html or pdf it looks like plain old R console output.

Why the difference?

Example:

```
library(datasets)
library(dplyr)
data <- ToothGrowth

data %>%
   group_by(supp, dose) %>%
   summarise(n=(), mean=mean(len), sd=sd(len))
```

R Markdown:

````
```{r}
library(datasets)
library(dplyr)
data <- ToothGrowth

data %>%
  group_by(supp, dose) %>%
  summarise(n=n(), mean=mean(len), sd=sd(len))
```
````

In RStudio:
[image: RStudio chunk]

In HTML and PDF:
[image: HTML and PDF output]

Comment: Rmarkdown code would give a better idea.

Comment: Updated question, Thank you!

Comment: works fine for me.. maybe  check the settings (next to knittr menu in RStudio) and check that the setting for HTML is set to use default theme.

Comment: The source code for the generated html file will have all the css embedded as  style tags at the top .

Comment: it seems like your RStudio is opening the data in View() . The regular Rmarkdown output is very much like your other output. Look at some online tutrorials for example output. You can stylise these chunks by enclosing them in HTML div tags

Comment: you can use `knitr::kable()` to format dataframes

Comment: I tried using kable and it doesn't change this behaviour. Maybe I should open an issue at the repo.

Comment: Use the knitr `kable()` function. You may also need to set `results='asis'` in the chunk header.

Comment: I have tried kable, no change. I have also tried results='asis' and it breaks the output apart.

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting "pretty" datatables printed in a similar manner that they are displayed inside an Rmd file. I do not know how to produce an exact replication of that output inside an HTML format.

I do know how to produce a similar output in an HTML document. You need the [DT package](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/DT/) which itself uses `htmlwidgets` as a dependency.

Once you've added the library to your document use the following call inside a chunk:

```
DT::datatable(data)
```

This will give you an interactive table in your **HTML** output.

This will not work in PDF documents because the libraries require the use of javascript. This is noted in [Yihui Xie's documentation of bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html-widgets.html). If you must use PDF you will need to fallback on a standard output.

Comment: Thanks Tim, at this point, PDF doesnt matter, I try to avoid the format anyway. I guess I can use other packages like DT to get something similar but I thought there was something wrong with the functionality. My question is probably really about why isnt this integrated as a default or at least something you can set in the options. I will bring it up in the repo. The output in RStudio is quite nice, I was just trying to understand why they are not the same. Its not an unreasonable expectation from the user's point of view. Thanks for the suggestion!